# Command line automaticly new line

Tags: command-line, 22.04

Sorry if my english is too bad : in Ubuntu when it starts you have lines line 'cloud-init'..I know it's possible to "ignore them" but having Ubuntu creating the line you are using to enter your command automatically.
To make is easier : you start to write things
System write something, for example "cloud init [...]"
You keep writing : you can't read anything because your line was 'cut'

Long time before I view a command that can just re-create the line at the end of the terminal without the interruption.

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] with a screenshot

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it the desktop, the server, or the cloud service provider specific version? If you are using a cloud service, which one? Edit your question and add these information.

Comment: Using Ubuntu server without GUI (22.04)